# IE8 text cover bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I encountered a strange bug in IE8.My page like this below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>IE8 bug</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class='content'>
           <a class='inner-text'>你好hello world</a>
           <a class='wid' >ssss</a>
       </div>
    </body>
    <style type='text/css'>
    .wid{
        border: 1px solid red;
        }
    .content{
        position: fixed;
        }
    .inner-text{
        display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

The bug is that the 'ssss' will cover part of the '你好hello world',and it appears conditions are these:

1) .content must be positioned fixed or absolute;

2) set .inner-text's display inline-block and it's innerHTML must contain non-ascii letters;

3)There must be DTD;

I got some solutions.one is change the '你好hello world' to '你 好 hello world'.But I want some better solutions,would you like to help me?

Comment: I don't see the bug, with or without the utf8 encoding. Can you post a screenshot? Also - have you tried setting `margin-left` on the `.wid` class?

Comment: I can reproduce this bug, but I don't have to have non-ascii letters.  It's the combination of `'inline-block'` on the 'inner-text' and `fixed` on the 'content' that causes the issue for me.  Are you saying that you want to fix it, but you must have those CSS rules in place?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Did you refresh the page?I just added the rendder image [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/regPH.jpg) and [code image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DwJKW.png)

Comment: It only happens on native IE8 for me, not if you use the dev tools to change the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finding that this is only in native IE8, and it non-ascii didn't make a difference for me.

With the styles you set I see this:

[image]

If I remove `.inner-text { display: inline-block; }` it fixes:

[image]

And if you have `.wid { display: inline-block; }` as well as the `.inner-text { display: inline-block; }` it also fixes.

[image]

Finally, a last image to show it still broke without the characters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much.If there is no spaces between hello and world,the bug will not appear.So I think spaces causes this bug,and non-ascii letters can reduce some spaces.